# How to detect a string literal

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I'm trying to detect if a template argument is a `char` pointer or `wchar_t` pointer, but

```
is_char_type<std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::value
```

is never `true`.
What am I doing wrong here, or is there a standard function for detecting character pointers?

```
template<typename T>
struct is_char_type : std::false_type {};

template<> struct is_char_type<char> : std::true_type {};
template<> struct is_char_type<unsigned char> : std::true_type {};
template<> struct is_char_type<signed char> : std::true_type {};
template<> struct is_char_type<wchar_t> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
void foo(T value)
{
  if constexpr (std::is_pointer<T>::value && 
  is_char_type<std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::value)
  {
    s << "'" << value << "',";
  }
}

foo("test");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that the type of `"test"` is `const char[]`, after decay-to-pointer it becomes `const char*`, then after `std::remove_pointer` you'll get `const char`, which doesn't match the specialization with specified type `char`.

You could also add template specializations for type `const char`, (and better for `volatile char` and `const volatile char`,) or use [`std::remove_cv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv) together, e.g.

```
is_char_type<std::remove_cv_t<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>>::value
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                      ~
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mvYRBaSSpwyZHpWY)